# Looping over operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I am writing a test for a type class and I was wondering if there is a way of looping and changing the operator? so loop over `[+, -, *, / , // ]`

so what I want to do is :

```py
for op in operators:
 assert 2 op my_type == 2 op my_type.num_atr # op being the operator +, - etc
```

so this would the same as

```py
assert 2 + my_type == 2 + my_type.num_atr
assert 2 - my_type == 2 - my_type.num_atr
assert 2 * my_type == 2 * my_type.num_atr
# ....
```

Is this somehow possible? I understand that this somewhat just syntactic sugar and that there are not too many operators but this would make it faster to change all of the tests at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `operator` module? Or write simply the operation as function.

```py
import operator

for op in (
    operator.add,
    operator.sub,
    operator.mul,
    operator.div,
    operator.floordiv,
):
    assert op(2, my_type) == op(2, my_type.num_atr)  # op being the operator +, - etc
```